# There's a type of question in the test which/that

Tags: grammar

*There's a type of question in the test **which/that** asks you to compare the subjects in question constantly.*

I was writing the above sentence using "which", and Grammarly suggested changing "which" to "that". As far as I know, we can use both "which" and "that" in this case. Am I missing something? If there's an underlying grammar rule here, I'd love to see other cases where we must start a relative clause complementing an object noun with "that" instead of "which".

Comment: You are right: both "which" and "that" are fine. Generally, there are no relative clauses where "that" is mandatory. But there are certainly examples where it is strongly preferred over a _wh_ relativ , for example in "That fish is the biggest (**that**) I have ever seen" /  "All **that** I ask for is a little peace and quiet".

Comment: Incidentally, some would say that yours is an example of postposing of a relative clause, i.e. one where the relative clause is located in postposed position at the end of the clause that contains its antecedent, which can lead to ambiguity as to what the antecedent is. But in this case I don't think there's any ambiguity since "question" provides a more salient antecedent than "test".

Answer (score 1):

> There's a type of question in the test **which/that** asks you to compare the subjects in question constantly.

You can use either one.  For relative clauses, there are no situations in which we must use the relativiser **that**. In fact, **that** has limitations in its use: it can be used only in defining relative clauses but not in non-defining ones.

We use **that** in **that-clauses**, but they are a different construction.

Comment: The antecedent to that or which here is the test, so it really doesn't work. But the meaning is that it's the question that asks you to compare this to that.

Answer (score -1):

In the test, there's a type of question which/that constantly asks you to compare (the) subjects.

You can use that or which, but "in the test" should come at the beginning or those words refer to test and not to "the type of question".